# Store one of three phone numbers as the primary number in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a database table that has three columns for phone numbers (mobile, home & work). Is there a way I can design the database to be able to select one of them as the main phone number for when a call is to be made through an API to the user in a UI (e.g. a web page)?

Right now, I only just have the three columns with nothing to identify the primary number.

Referring to the image below, I want to be able to persist a primary number.

[image]

Comment: just add a column like is_primary as a bit to identify the primary phone number surely?

Comment: Create one more column (ENUM) - e.g. PrimaryNo - with a value of M, H, or W?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, did you read the question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of your program, but you can just add some sort of identifier for which number should be primary based on the user's selection. It could be as simple as an integer that is assigned to the primary number based on which radio-button the user selects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't splay an array (of numbers) across columns.  Have another table.  In that, you can have a flag saying which is primary and an enum saying which type each is.  And allow for more than exactly one of each type.  Plus allow for more types.